# KIK bot send message to user's friends after user permission

Tags: javascript, kik

I'm creating KIK bot.
My goal is to send messages to user's friend after this user permission.
But I haven't found anything that can help me. 
During process I've found 'kid.sign' function, but I don't clearly understand how it works. 
This is link to api: https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/kikjs

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on your bot some more.

Bots can't message other users unless the user has messages them first which might make your bot difficult to make. This users friend can't receive messages until that friend has also messaged the bot.

If those things are all good, and you are looking for the user to pick a friend to send the message to. Checkout https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/kikjs#social-graph Friend Picker. Note all kik-js stuff is in the browser so you would have to send the user a link to a webpage.

`kik.sign` is a function used for authenticating data sent back to your server from the webpage. You can sign the data before you send it, and authenticate it on your server to ensure it actually did come from that user

Comment: Have you seen bot Secret Admirer?
It can chat with user without user's permission.
All you need is just to select this user. 
Everything else is good with my bot. I can't understand how to make it possible like Secret Admirer